# Issues Applying css styles conditionally to a twitter-bootstrap table

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have a table containing a list of products.  Below the table I have a text field where a barcode is entered, if the barcode is found the matching row in the table should be highlighted.  i've read through many similar scenarios and as far as I can tell i'm doing everything as I should.  I can see in the  google dev console that the barcode I enter matches the only product currently in my table however for some reason the css doesn't get applied...  Any idea what i'm doing wrong here?/how I can go about fixing it?

my css:

```
.found {
    background-color: green;
}
```

my html table and input field:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Description</th>
         <th>Price</th>                        
         <th>Qty</th>
         <th>Barcode</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of ticket.items" [class.found]="item.Barcode === spotCheckBarcode">
            <td>{{item?.ProductDetail_Name}}</td>
            <td>{{item?.Amount}}</td>   
            <td>{{item?.Qty}}</td>
            <td>{{item?.Barcode}}</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>

   <form role="form" [formGroup]="spotCheckForm" (ngSubmit)="spotCheck(spotCheckForm.value.itemBarcode)">
        <input class="form-control" type="tel" placeholder="Enter item barcode" [formControl]="spotCheckForm.controls['itemBarcode']">
        <button class="btn btn-block" [disabled]="!spotCheckForm.controls['itemBarcode'].valid && busy"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</button>
    </form>
```

//my ts component function that sets spotCheckBarcode

```
spotCheck(itemBarcode: number) {                
    let found: boolean = false;     
     for (var i: number = 0; i < this.ticket.items.length; i++) {           
        if (itemBarcode === this.ticket.items[i].Barcode) {
            console.log('found!');
            found = true;               
            this.spotCheckBarcode = itemBarcode;                
        }       
    }       
    if (found == false) {
        console.log(`found in if statement: ${found}`);
        this.showError("Item not found on ticket");
    }           
}
```

Comment: did you try: .found td {
    background-color: green;
}

Comment: Could you create a quick plunker of this to make it a little easier to figure out what is going on.

Comment: @techLove that did it!!! Please add that as the answer, why did I have to apply it to the column as well as the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your class is not applied to td. you need to be bit more specific with css for table here.

```
.found td { background-color: green; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Err, that looks right, but let's dig it apart.

So for the css class not being applied, have you tried inspecting the element to see if the class is added to the `tr` and maybe the styling is being overwritten?

[image: Is the class attached]

[image: Search for the class]

[image: Is the style overriden]

Comment: Thanks for that very detailed answer:  It seems like the class is there, at the top I can see table tbody tr.found.  When I select tr.found however I can't see the found class anywhere in the css below it.  Does that mean it doesn't get attached?  i'm guessing it's bootstrap that overrides it?